# Adding products to spree without master price

Tags: spree

In Spree, how do I remove the pricing and thus all the ecommerce functionality? I want to use it more as a catalog reference and would not want prices to display. Additionally no add to cart or checkout things as well?

Comment: Spree is not for you then, simple.

Comment: I saw that `master_price` is a mandatory field.

Answer (score 0):

One can disable master_price by configuring spree initializer:

In config/initializers/spree.rb:

```
Spree.config do |config|
  ...
  config.require_master_price = false
  ...
end
```